# callback function before animate

Tags: jquery

Actually the callback function is called after animation completes

```
(selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback)
```

How could I call callback function before animation start?

> Or like this when animation is running at the meanwhile how can I call callback function?

Comment: `callback(); $(selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback);` , isn't it?

Comment: within the animate function.

Comment: Basically it's not a callback if you call it before something starts, is it??

Comment: What's the difference, C-Link?

Comment: you want it as parameter like `complete` ?

Comment: If you want to do callback while animation is running use the `step` or `progress` from jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Martin: when you call `callback(); $(selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback);`, these 2 functions **are not related**. For example, you cannot cancel the animate function if a condition is true. The case is clearer for `$.ajax`: `$.ajax` has a `beforeSend` function, you could stop the ajax in there. But if you call them as 2 functions, they are not related.

Comment: @Khanh what about `return` in callback() function with an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

if `callback` is a function, just call it before `animate`

```
callback();
(selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function animate(preCallback, postCallback) {

    // Create var to hold animating object if you want to use deffereds
    var animation;

    // Animation is about to start run preCallback()
    // If you don't want the animation to start until this is complete
    // You should look at returning a deffered object from the callback
    // or using another callback inside, warning : this can get messy.
    preCallback instanceof Function && preCallback();

    // Start the animation
    animation = $('#animation').animate({styles}, speed, easing, function() {
        // Once animation is finished run finished callback
        postCallback instanceof Function && postCallback();
    });

    // Alternative Return animation as deffered so further 
    // complete callbacks can be chained to it with .done()
    return $.when(animation);
}

animate(function() {
    // preCallback code, this will NOT stop animation from starting
    // before it is complete without further logic
}, function() { 
    // postCallback code
}).done(function() {
    // further callback using deffered object
});
```

As a note, on the `preCallback` it would be better to run this code and then call animate from it once it is complete, removing the need to add this capability at all.